# Calculus I - Math Gateway Exam help

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Currently in my college Calculus class, and apparently any math class at my university we have to take these Gateway exams that are $10$ random questions and you have to get $9/10$ correct (or $90%$ via partial credit in the end). otherwise you fail the course regardless of your grade for the class.

Luckily, you can take it over multiple times, I have taken it once and have not passed it. So now I am looking for some good study questions. Luckily its also only on Power Rule, Product Rule, Quotient Rule, and chain Rule, so only deriving questions are on the test.

Apparently I didn't study enough of the "complicated" ones, Is there a reference or a good list of equations to derive via a website, or even if a bunch were thrown at me so i can study up on those.

one example that I know I need to study is

> $$ \frac{\ln x}{(x^2)^{1/5}}. $$

Comment: ...and the question **is** ....? (I'm almost sure what you meant but I think it'd be better, for you and all, you write it explicitly).

Comment: the question is the last line in my statement "Is there a reference or a good list of equations to derive via website, or if a bunch of them were just listed so i can study on those." I just need to study difficult Derivations. The rest is all a preface of why it is important, which i guess i could of left out.

Comment: The question's still inexistent: do you want to know how to differentiate the function you gave? To write "to study" is completely unclear.

Comment: I know the concepts of each rule, but when I took the test it was a bunch of ones that threw me because I didn't study more complicated equations of derivatives. The idea is to uncover where i mess up when i do more complicated derivatives. but regardless I think Mark has answered my question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://cow.math.temple.edu/

Click on Calculus I, then Chapter 4 - Techniques and Theory of Differentiation.

Sections 1 and 3 are the exact subjects you are being tested on. This site is an excellent way to review. I used it to get ready for Calc II when I had taken Calc I 7 years prior. Result - I got an A in Calc II.

Comment: This looks to be what I am looking for, they have a range of equations i can study and become proficient, and see where i am tripping up on the complicated ones. thanks!